# How to center a vector in an image?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
public class LetterGenerator {
    private static final int NUM_OF_TILE_COLORS = 8;
    private final TextPaint mPaint = new TextPaint();
    private final Rect mBounds = new Rect();
    private final Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();
    private final char[] mFirstChar = new char[1];
    private final TypedArray mColors;
    private final int mTileLetterFontSize;
    private final Bitmap mDefaultBitmap;
    private final int mWidth;
    private final int mHeight;

    public LetterGenerator(Context context) {
        final Resources res = context.getResources();
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mColors = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.avatar_colors);
        mTileLetterFontSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tile_letter_font_size);
        mDefaultBitmap = drawableToBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_person_white_24dp));
        mWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.letter_tile_size);
        mHeight = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.letter_tile_size);
    }

    public Bitmap getCircularLetterTile(String displayName) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas c = mCanvas;
        c.setBitmap(bitmap);
        c.drawColor(pickColor(displayName));

        if (displayName.trim().length() == 0) {
            c.drawBitmap(mDefaultBitmap, dpToPx(4) ,dpToPx(4),  null);
        } else {
            final char firstChar = displayName.trim().charAt(0);
            mFirstChar[0] = Character.toUpperCase(firstChar);
            mPaint.setTextSize(mTileLetterFontSize);
            mPaint.getTextBounds(mFirstChar, 0, 1, mBounds);
            c.drawText(mFirstChar, 0, 1, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2 + (mBounds.bottom - mBounds.top) / 2, mPaint);
        }

        return getCircularBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output;

        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        float radius = 0;

        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            radius = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        } else {
            radius = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }

    private static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

It creates an avatar letter. As default it sets an XML vector icon. But the icon is a bit of. I can't seem to figure out which arguments I need to pass on line `c.drawBitmap(mDefaultBitmap, dpToPx(4) ,dpToPx(4),  null)`. The `dpToPx` method is:

```
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

What I get:

[image]

How can I center the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
c.drawBitmap(mDefaultBitmap, dpToPx(4) ,dpToPx(4),  null);
```

To:

```
c.drawBitmap(mDefaultBitmap, mWidth / 2 - mDefaultBitmap.getWidth() / 2, mHeight / 2 - mDefaultBitmap.getHeight() / 2)
```